# Laravel dynamic where clauses

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I would like to create a dynamic query with laravel ORM. In my example:

```
 $query = Task::orderBy('customer_family_name');

 if (array_key_exists('date', $request->filter)) {
     if($request->filter['date'] != null) {
        $query = $query->whereDate(....);
     }
 }

 ..... more filters


 if (array_key_exists('search', $request->filter)) {
       if(strlen($request->filter['search']) > 1) {
            $searchText = $request->filter['search'];
            $query = $query->where('customer_family_name', $searchText.'%');
            }
        }
 }

 $Tasks = $query->get();
```

But it is not working as expected. I thought that laravel will push all where elements, so that ALL where clauses must be met.

But the search for a family name is not working. Do i something wrong? How can i combine it correct? Is there a way to display the SQL Query with orm?

**Edit: ok found out that is another problem, my query looks like:**

```
"select * from [tasks] where [state_id] in (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) and [customer_family_name] = ? and [regulator_user_id] in (?, ?, ?) or [regulator_user_id] is null order by [customer_family_name] asc"
```

And my filter:

```
if (array_key_exists('regulator', $request->filter)) {

      $regulator_array = explode(",", $request->filter['regulator']);

      if(is_array($regulator_array)) {
                $query->whereIn('regulator_user_id', $regulator_array)->orWhereNull('regulator_user_id');
       }

  }
```

It looks like that the orWhereNull is the problem. I would like to return every row where

regulator_user_id is in that array
AND all where regulator_user_id IS NULL

But all other filters should work as expected.

How can i do that?

Comment: `$Tasks = $query->toSql();` will show you sql code. Better use debugbar by `barryvdh`. Also, try `$query = $query->where('customer_family_name', 'LIKE', $searchText.'%');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok ill found the correct solution:

Ill need my own query function to combine an Where with an orWhereNull:

```
     if(is_array($regulator_array)) {
          $query = $query->where(function($query) use($regulator_array)  {
               $query->whereIn('regulator_user_id', $regulator_array)
                        ->orWhereNull('regulator_user_id');
                });
            }
```

Now the query works fine. Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be re-saving to your `$query` variable:

```
$query = $query->whereDate(....);
```

Change it to this (and for your other filters):

```
$query->whereDate(....);
```

Your final command :

```
$Tasks = $query->get();
```

Will then return the proper data according to the extra queries that were added to your `$query` object.

Comment: Thanks - i tried this before too, same problem. It returns me 4 rows, where it should return only 1. It seems like it automatically makes an "orWhere" - is there a way to debug a query?

Comment: Ill already found out that the problem is the orWhereNull() - Eloquent makes this global, and not for the exact part of the query. See my Edit please.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned from Jhonny Walker you shouldn't save every time the 
$query but use the $query->where each time.
One line before the $Tasks = $query->get();  
try to debug the mysql command that is generated with the following command.

```
dd($query->toSql());
```

If you want paste the result in order to help you with the where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use this sweet eloquent method when(), so you don't have to use if statement and break the method chaining, instead you got fluent query building.
[Eloquent when()](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_when)